# Stored Procedure to display two set of results using joins

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

Lets say I have two tables

```
  Create table tblMessages
  (
  MessageId int primary key identity,
  Title nvarchar(max),
  Body nvarchar(max),
  MsgFrom nvarchar(10),
  MsgTo nvarchar(10),
  SentDateTime datetime,
  MsgRead int default 0
  )
```

and

```
  Create table tblAllUsers
  ( 
   Id int primary key identity,
   UserId nvarchar(100,
   FullName nvarchar(50)
  )
```

and here is a stored procedure that i tried display my messages for the logged in user

```
  Alter proc spExtractInbox
  @UserId nvarchar(10)
  as
  begin
  Select * from tblMessages 
  INNER JOIN
  tblAllUsers ON tblMessages.MsgTo = tblAllUsers.UserId
  where tblMessages.MsgTo=@UserId order by tblMessages.SentDateTime desc
  end
```

The above query works just fine to display message and UserId of the Sender(MsgFrom) but i want to display the name of the Sender which is stored in tblAllUsers.I am using this in a grdiview.I am not sure if i am explaining it the best way.

The problem is join is already joining the two tables depending on tblMessages.MsgTo = tblAllUsers.UserId. So how is it possible for me to do tblMessages.MsgFrom = tblAllUsers.UserId to get the Senders name?

Comment: add before where clause: inner join tblAllUsers on tblMessages.MsgFrom = tblAllUsers.UserId

Comment: and replace select * by the column names you really need from your proc

Comment: @JulienVavasseur - "The objects "tblAllUsers" and "tblAllUsers" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Alias (AS aliasname) in order to double join on the same table:

```
Select ... from tblMessages AS msg 
INNER JOIN tblAllUsers AS ut
    ON msg.MsgTo = ut.UserId
INNER JOIN tblAllUsers AS uf
    ON msg.MsgFrom = uf.UserId
where msg.MsgTo=@UserId or msg.MsgFrom=@UserId
order by tblMessages.SentDateTime desc
```

Alias also make your life easier because you don't have to repeat the full table name each time.
See [Using Table Aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Add the columns you need to the select (msg.Title, ut.Fullname, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to allUsers twice once for the sender once for the receiver...

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tblMessages 
  INNER JOIN tblAllUsers Rec
    ON tblMessages.MsgTo = Rec.UserId
  INNER JOIN tblAllusers Snd
    on tblMessages.MsgFrom = Rec.userID
  WHERE Rec.MsgTo=@UserId 
  ORDER BY tblMessages.SentDateTime desc
```

Limit * to only needed fields.
Notice the second join to tblAllusers with alias used.